# MFC:throw "Access violation" when execute "IHTMLTable::insertRow"

Tags: mfc

I want to create rows and cells in the CDHtmlDialog. Here is the code my wrote:

```
void CHtmlTableTestDlg::OnDocumentComplete(LPDISPATCH pDisp, LPCTSTR szUrl)
{
    IHTMLTable* table;
    this->GetElement(_T("Table"),(IHTMLElement**)&table); 
    IDispatch* dispatch;
    table->insertRow(1,&dispatch);
}
```

Here is the html of the table:

```
<table id="Table">
    <tr>
        <th>Column</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I debugged the project and got the error below when execute "table->insertRow(1,&dispatch)"

Unhandled exception at 0x3fa53780 in HtmlTableTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000001.

I have uploaded my test project:
http://top720.com/Temp/HtmlTableTest.zip

How to create rows and cells base on the CDHtmlDialog?

Thank you for any helps in in advance.

Comment: Have you checked table is a valid pointer?

Comment: I am sorry that I am a beginer of C++. How to check the pointer is valid? I use "if" to check and pass.

`code`
if(table) this->MessageBox(L"table is a valid pointer！");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just cast between `IHTMLElement` and `IHTMLTable`. Try this:

```
IHTMLElement* element;
if(S_OK == this->GetElement(_T("Table"),(IHTMLElement**)&element)) {
   IHTMLTable* table;
   if(S_OK == element->QueryInterface(&table)) {
      IDispatch* dispatch;
      table->insertRow(1,&dispatch);
      table->Release();
      table = NULL;
   }
}
```

It would also be worth reading an [introduction to COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwa2bx93%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I Had converted IHtmlElement objects to IHtmlTable objects success in a C# project, so I considered that the html objects could be converted in the same way in the C++ project.